# how to read multiple value from joined table in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

how to read multiple value from joined table in codeigniter

this is model.php

```
public function all_village_info($id = NULL) {
    $this->db->select('tbl_village.*', FALSE);
    $this->db->select('tbl_school.*', FALSE);
    $this->db->from('tbl_village');
    $this->db->join('tbl_school', 'tbl_school.school_id=tbl_village.school_id', 'left');
    if (!empty($id)) {
        $this->db->where('tbl_village.village_id', $id);
        $query_result = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query_result->row();
    } else {
        $query_result = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query_result->result();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

and this is view.php

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-sm-1" >VILLAGE</th>
            <th class="col-sm-1" >ZONE</th>
            <th class="col-sm-1" >SCHOOL</th>                    
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>                    
        <?php if (!empty($all_village_info)):
            foreach ($all_village_info as $v_village) :
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $v_village->village_name ?></td> 
                    <td><?php echo $v_village->zone_name ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $v_village->school_name ?></td>                                                                     
                </tr>
                <?php
            endforeach;
            ?>
<?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

value in sql_is like

```
|-------------|------------|
|village_name |school_id   |
|-------------|------------|
|Bhiwani      |1,2,3       |
```

view is as

```
    |-------------|------------|
    |Village      |School      |
    |-------------|------------|
    |Bhiwani      |School 1    |
```

i want to show like

```
|-------------|-------------------------------|
|Village      |School                         |
|-------------|-------------------------------|
|Bhiwani      |School 1, School 2, School 3   |
```

how can i do that ? help plz
how to read multiple value from joined table in codeigniter

Comment: Please post your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias of the table and then select those

**NOTE :** I highly recommend you to use * if and only if your using all the columns else it will make your query bit slower.

/* You can take an alias for the table and select * from that, I have followed chaining method. */

```
$this->db
    ->select('v.*, s.*')
    ->from('tbl_village v')
    ->join('tbl_school s', 's.school_id = v.school_id', 'left')
    ->get()
    ->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem :

Please change your modal function :

`all_village_info:`

```
public function all_village_info($id = NULL) {
    $this->db->select('tbl_village.*', FALSE);
    $this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(tbl_school.school_name ORDER BY tbl_school.school_id) as school_name', FALSE);
    $this->db->from('tbl_village');
    $this->db->join('tbl_school', 'FIND_IN_SET(tbl_school.school_id, tbl_village.school_id) > 0', 'left');
    if (!empty($id)) {
        $this->db->where('tbl_village.village_id', $id);
        $query_result = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query_result->row();
    } else {
        $query_result = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query_result->result();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I hope it will help you.